# firebase database filtering is not working. Need some assistance

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, filter

I have a simple test database that I cant get to filter. I indexed the category in the rules:

```
"questions":{
        ".indexOn": ["category"]
      },
```

My filter for the quiz app:

```
/questions.json?orderBy="category"&equalTo="Basics"&print=pretty
```

and my database:

```
"-MKoucSP33zm4jC43AnY" : {
    "title" : {
      "answers" : [ {
        "score" : 30,
        "text" : "Pineapple"
      }, {
        "score" : 5,
        "text" : "Ham"
      }, {
        "score" : 20,
        "text" : "Yogurt"
      }, {
        "score" : 10,
        "text" : "Crab"
      } ],
      "category" : "Basics",
      "questionId" : "101",
      "questionImage" : "",
      "questionLink" : "",
      "questionText" : "What topping do you like the best on pizza?"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `category` property is nested under the `title` node, so the property you need to order/filter on is `title/category`:

```
/questions.json?orderBy="title/category"&equalTo="Basics"&print=pretty
```

You'll also need to update your index definition for that path, so:

```
"questions": { ".indexOn": "title/category" }
```

Working example: [https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/64596200/questions.json?orderBy="title/category"&equalTo="Basics"](https://stackoverflow.firebaseio.com/64596200/questions.json?orderBy=%22title/category%22&equalTo=%22Basics%22)

Comment: I thought for sure I tried that but guess I didn't. thanks for the solution.